# Antivirus content Scanning in a J2EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, upload, attachment, multipart, antivirus

Please suggest the possible approaches in implementing antivirus scanning for files being uploaded into a Java/J2EE based Web-Application.

Regards,
kk

Answer (score 0):

It would help to tell us a bit more about the requirements you have and why your application needs to do this.

But I'd suggest not to do this in your own web application. Instead you could for example save them to a folder on your server system which is protected by an antivirus scanner.

If your application really has to do it, I'd suggest using an online virus scanner and let it check there.

*Small note: Don't use the term J2EE anymore if not maintaining an ancient application.*

Comment: Antivirus installed server is being used and along with that we had to use a scanner. ClamAV is supported for this, working till now.